# How to get the lines that include only a single group of letters using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to find the lines that include only one group of letters. The file includes only digits and lower case letters. No space or anything.

Good example:

```
39568250269955376311912572precondition005426787530581443236416842014020466976603
```

Bad example:

```
1895853531360579the3170095290529923mathematici2779805995331496368099837070an1084
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'gsub(/[a-z]+/,"&")==1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of above code, it is only for explaining purposes for running code kindly use above mentioned code itself.

```
awk '                    ##Starting awk program here.
gsub(/[a-z]+/,"&")==1    ##Using gsub function of awk to substitute all small letters occurrences with same values itself.
                         ##Then checking count of it,if it is equal to 1 then print current line.
                         ##awk works on method of condition and action, in above condition is mentioned but NO action so by default print of current line will happen.
' Input_file             ##mentioning Input_file name here, which is being passed to awk program.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that awesome explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Regex with `sed`

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]*[a-z]\{1,\}[0-9]*$/p'
```

or with `grep`:

```
 grep -x -E '[0-9]*[a-z]+[0-9]*'
```

or with `awk`:

```
 awk '$0 ~ "^[0-9]*[a-z]+[0-9]*$"'
```

Either means the same - filter only the lines that start with zero or more numbers, followed by one or more lowercase letters followed by zero or more numbers only.

Comment: Made it work using your regex with grep, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional tool for such tasks is `grep`, e:g:

```
grep -E -x '[^[:alpha:]]*[[:alpha:]]+[^[:alpha:]]*' file
```

Comment: i liked the -x flag

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the whole file and do something like `if [[ $line =~ ^[A-Za-z]+$ ]]` then print out the line.

Note that you must iterate over each line of the file first and then you would be able to perform the command.

Answer (score 0):

Transliterate all digits to linefeeds, then count lines with letters in:

```
echo 39568250269955376311912572precondition005426787530581443236416842014020466976603 | tr '[0-9]' '\n'| grep -c [:alpha:]
1

echo  1895853531360579the3170095290529923mathematici2779805995331496368099837070an1084 | tr '[0-9]' '\n'| grep -c [:alpha:]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

This short `awk` should do (using characters as the field separator)

```
awk -F'[a-z]+' '{print NF}' file
```

- `0` nothing on line
- `1` only digits, no letter
- `2` one group of letter (what you want)
- any number larger than `2`, more than one group of letter

If you like to print the line:

```
awk -F'[a-z]+' 'NF==2' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/^[[:alnum:]]+$/{s/[[:alpha:]]+/&/2;t;//p}' file
```

Focus on lines that only contain alphanumeric characters. Then if the line contains 2 or more groups of alphabetic characters, reject it and reject the line if it contains no alphabetic characters too.

N.B. This will accept a line with no digits and only alphabetic characters.
If digits must always be present, use:

```
sed -nE '/^[[:alnum:]]+$/{/[[:digit:]]/s/[[:alpha:]]+/&/2;t;//p}' file
```